# UIKit/UIKit.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I have installed the `Xcode 6.0.1` and `Xcode 5.1.1` in my system.
When I create project in `Xcode 6.0.1` it is working fine, when I create project in `Xcode 5.1.1` and build the same getting **Proprocessor issue as `UIKit/UIKit.h file not found`.**

I tried to add the framework explicitly in Build phases and there also the `UIKit` is not found.
Same for `Foundation.framework` also.

This issue is started once after installing the `Xcode 6.`

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this issue after leaving my development computer on or in sleep mode for an extended time (1-2 months). It disappeared after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Add pch file in you in xcode project to resolve this very easily.

- Make new file: ⌘cmd+N
- iOS/Mac > Other > PCH File > YourProject-Prefix.pch.
- Project > Build Settings > Search: "Prefix Header".
- Under "Apple LLVM 6.0" you will get the Prefix Header key.
- Type in: "YourProjectName/YourProject-Prefix.pch".
- Clean project: ⌘cmd+⇧shift+K
- Build project: ⌘cmd+B
  [image: add pch file]

Comment: I tried the same it is not working. The project is working fine in the Xcode 6 but Facing issue in Xcode 5.1.1.

Comment: Yes that is issue .You should create you project in older version than than if you use it in newer version than its fine. actully i assume so many story board changes(like lunchscreen,module) are there in xcode 6 so this is issue. Even i used to create project in xoce 5.1.1 and than than run it in xocde 6 so even in older version it may work if any time it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that might help someone very new like me on the x-code ios ecosystem:

for me the answer was to change  back to ios  form OS X in the build settings I really don't know why I changed it in the first place (probably because it told me to change from beta and i figured here I can change to something that is not beta not realizing entirely what I'm doing).

After that and

- Deleting Xcode Beta and reinstalling  Xcode (6.1 - current stable)
- Updating the ios, version of my device (iphone 4s to 8.1.2 latest)
- Changing signature in Code signing identity to an acceptable one (Provisioning Profile -Automatic)

Everything was going well, and I was able to submit the app via Xcode.
P.s. maybe some of the heavy lifting of deleting wasn't necessary but it seemed to be the safest bet.